# 'The Microsoft Access database engine cannot open or write to the file' error when opening access database from VB.net

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, error-handling

So whenever I try to write some data into one of my databases through VB.net, I'm getting this error which says it's because either the database is open or permission is not granted to me to write or read the database.

I have made sure the permission is grated to 'everyone' for read and write and also there's no database open either. But the error still shows. Having done some research, it says I should move my database on my local server which it already is.

The error occurs in the last line when I run my program:

```
provider = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="
        datafile = "C:\Users\Hamza\Desktop\POS_database"
        connstring = provider & datafile
        myconnection.connectionstring = connstring
        myconnection.Open()
```

Are there any other ways I could solve this problem?

Comment: Add the code where the error occurs to you question with the edit link.

Comment: @Mary  just done.

Comment: I don't see the file extension name in your sample code? You need the full path name and the file name here.

Comment: Your connection string is wrong. See https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal The full path name is defined in the 'datafile' variable, line 2?

Comment: @KenWhite I don't see anything wrong with it. Just compared it with what there was in the link. Could you specify please?

Comment: The full path **and file name** are not defined in the `datafile` variable on line 2. You're missing the file extension.

Comment: Don't build a connection string like that in the first place. Use a connection string builder - in your case, an `OleDbConnectionStringBuilder`. Then you wouldn't end up doing silly things like having the `Data Source` attribute half in a variable named `provider`.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in the comments, you are missing the file extension on your data file name. If you're using ACE then, presumably, it is an ACCDB file. You should use a connection string builder and the correct file path:

```vb
Dim builder As New OleDbConnectionStringBuilder With
               {
                   .Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
                   .DataSource = "C:\Users\Hamza\Desktop\POS_database.accdb"
               }

Using connection As New OleDbConnection(builder.ConnectionString)
    connection.Open()

    'Use connection here.
End Using
```

Also, if the file is on the desktop of the current user then you shouldn't hard-code the path like that:

```vb
.DataSource = Path.Combine(My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories.Desktop, "POS_database.accdb")
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your advice and help. I did as you suggested, but now every time I run the program it says the file Cannot be found.  This is what I had put:                               
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0",
                   .DataSource = "C:\Users\Hamza\Documents.accdb"

Comment: @HamzaAsim, do you really have a file named 'Documents.accdb' in your personal folder, or do you maybe have a file with some other name in your 'Documents' folder?

Comment: Yes You were right, I rechecked and typed in the right file path. But now when I run the program the error I get is : 'Column 'CustID' does not allow nulls.' Even though the field in my database isn't even set to "not accept null". Sorry hope you can help with this.

Comment: @HamzaAsim, if you are getting that error message then you have been able to successfully connect to the database so the question you asked here has been answered. If you now have a different question then you need to post that separately, with all the information specific to that question.